# Redirect To Action MVC convert to FILE RESULT

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, return, fileresult

This is my code for Download a File in my MVC App. Im having a weird error and I cant a way to put it right. The error is > 
***Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.FileResult'***

What I want with this code is, that while theres a file download it, but if theres not file(null) then it just dont do nothing or dont return nothing

```
 public FileResult Download(string Doc)
 {

    string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/"), Doc);

    if (fullPath == null)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);

        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, Doc);
    }

        return RedirectToAction("List");
         }
```

Comment: No, Raphael. It is not the same.

Comment: If you think that your question was wrongfully closed as duplicate, then *you* have to edit your question and explain *why* it is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your action method return type to `ActionResult`

Both `RedirectResult` and `FileResult` are inheriting from this `ActionResult` abstract class.

Also your if condition does not makes sense! It will always be `false` as the Path.Combine will give you a non null string value. May be you want to check the file exist in the disk ?

```
public ActionResult Download(string Doc)
{    
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/"), Doc);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);

        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, Doc);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

Your code  should be compilable now.

Comment: With that, my code doesn't download anything or return null

Comment: That has nothing to do with the return type change. Put a breakpoint in your method and see whether it is running as expected.

Comment: public ActionResult Download(string Doc)
        {
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/"), Doc);

            if (fullPath == null)
            {

                return RedirectToAction("List");
              
            }
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, Doc);
        }

Comment: I put it that way, it does the downloading, but when theres not file it crushed

Comment: See my updated answer. Your if condition was wrong.

Comment: With your code it does the downloading but when theres no file Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path2 and I dont want this error.

Comment: TBH, i never returned with the content type `MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet`. What sort of files are you trying to return ?

Comment: Im returning PDFs File

Comment: yea. It should work. I just verified it locally. What error are you getting ?

Comment: Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: path2"

Comment: string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/"), Doc);         Because the object Im calling has info but doesnt have file in it

Comment: is the value of `Doc` null ? you get that exception from `Combine` method when the value of `Doc` is null

Comment: Yes, Doc is null. I dont want getting that error if Doc is null. I which the controller dont do nothing while clicking dowloading

Comment: do a null on doc before entering your other if condition. If the value of Doc is null, return some other result ( The RedirectResult ?? or an error message back to the user)

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Let me work it out.  Thanks. I'll reply in a second.

Comment: If I do this: if (Doc == null)
            {
                return View("List");
            }     then it gaves me an error Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source.  
Source Error: 


Line 49: <div class="code-cut">
Line 50: 
Line 51:     @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(
Line 52:         Columns =>
Line 53:         {

Comment: I thought it was juts going to stay at the same page but no. :s xD

Comment: It will not. because this method will be executed when user clicked on the link from some other page and reach here. So wherever you are rendering those links, you can check the existence of a file in a efficient manner and show only those links